# Self referencing an array element in a Mongoose populate query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My parent Mongoose schema, `Study`, looks like this:

```
const StudySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
   series: [{ 
      type: { 
         name: String,
         states: [{
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, 
            ref: 'State'
         }]
      }
   }]
})
```

And the nested child schema, `State` , looks like this:

```
const State = new mongoose.Schema({
   name: String,
   data: number,
   seriesId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
   studyId: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
})
```

I want to perform a *populate* like this when retrieving a study:

```
this.studyModel
  .findById(studyId)
  .select('series')
  .populate([
    {
      path: 'series.state',
      match: {
        studyId: studyId,
        seriesId: 'series._id', // HERE'S THE ISSUE
      }
    }
  ])
```

But the problem is that, in the line I've specified, I have no access to *series._id* since Mongoose does not understand what *series* is in the *match* context (cannot use *series._id* ), although it does in the *path* context (can use *series.state*).

I want to populate the *state* element of the *state* array inside *series* that matches the studyId (no problem) and the seriesId, but I don't know how to self reference the series in the match of the populate query.